# reading data from another db

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have main database called db1. There is also another database called db2. Sometimes I need to get data from db2. Is it better to directly get data from db2 or to make view in db1?

Comment: Lots of factors to consider here. Is there a fast connection between databases? Is it a lot of data? Is it likely for either database to move? What do you mean by "make view in db1", this would still have to access db2?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'm not really that knowledgeable about databases but there are 2 ways for me to implement this thing. First is that I reference db2 when I make a querry in db1. 
SELECT *
FROM db2.table1

or I first create view (create view v_db1 SELECT * FROM db2.table1)
and then when I need that table in db2 I just SELECT * from v_db1

I'd like to know when to use 1st way or 2nd way. And what is the difference between those 2.
I hope i made it clearer what I'm thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting data from db2 you should create views in db2 for each query. Why? To create interfaces.

If someone will make changes in db2 he don't know your queries which are executed from db1. Your queries can stop working. If you create views for your queries in db2 and from db1 query view@db2 anyone who change structure in db2 will see invalid view in case his changes damaged your queries.

Of course I mean situation when your queries are embedded in packages or views. If you just query for analytic purpose it make no difference if you do it directly, with view on db1 or view on db2 just do as it is suitable for you. But good practice is setting interfaces so I would recommend to create view on db2 for datasets your later querying from db1. It can also make sense to create additional view or synonym on db1 side to have both side interface.

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to set up a driver for connectng to DB2, a TNS connection entry for Oracle to connect with and a database link in Oracle to point to the connection.

The important thing is that you try, as far as possible, to insulate changes in one DB from the other.

I've this done different ways but this has worked for me;

1. For each table you are querying in DB2 create a DB2 view of JUST the columns you want from that table.
2. Create a view in Oracle that queries DB2_VIEW@DB2_database. Although not strictly necessary just query the columns you want - its good practice.
3. Create a synonym for the view and query through that. If the source of the data changes and the view is replaced by a different one you can switch the synonym to point at the new view instead of changing your code.

**Summary:**
Unless I've misunderstood you seem to be asking should I query the table directly in DB2 or should I go through views? I suggest that going through views insulates you from changes at either end to some extent so use the views.